# An inference in predicate logic that has to be established using resolution method

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I have been struggling with breaking down this logic problem with the use of resolution method. Below is what i have done. I feel it is incorrect and humbly need your assistance. Thanks

Problem: ∃x(p(x) → q(x)) → ¬∀xp(x) |= ∃x ¬p(x)

What i have done.

¬∀xp(x)

∃x¬p(x)

¬p(a)

∃x(¬p(x) ∨ q(x)) → ∀xp(x)

¬∃x(¬p(x) ∨ q(x)) ∨ ∀xp(x)

∀x¬(¬p(x) ∨ q(x)) ∨ ∀xp(x)

∀x (p(x) ∧ ¬q(x)) ∨ ∀xp(x)

∀x∀y(p(x) ∧ ¬q(x)) ∨ p(y))

(p(x) ∧ ¬q(x)) ∨ p(y)

(p(x) ∨ p(y)) ∧ (¬q(x) ∨ p(y))

p(x), p(y) ←, p(y)←q(x), ← p(a)

p(x), p(y) ←, ← p(a)

p(y) ←, ← p(a)

←

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I don't see where you add the negation of the objective (RHS) to the list of the disjunctions of the hypotheses, an operation which is at the very basis of the (Robinson) resolution method

Comment: @Jean, perhaps you could help me with that and show me how the breakdown could be done correctly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $p(x)\equiv x=x$ and $q(x)\equiv x\ne x$. Then clearly $p(x)\to q(x)$ is false for all $x$, i.e., there is no $x$ with $p(x)\to q(x)$, i.e., $\exists x(p(x)\to q(x))$ is false, hence $\exists x(p(x)\to q(x))\to\text{whatever}$ is true. You will however hardly be able to prove $\exists x\neg p(x)$.

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution. I suppose in this case ∀x∀z(¬p(x) ∨ r(z)), ∀x(r(x) → p(x)) |= ∀xp(x) ∨ ∀xq(x). Would this be correct? domain: {1}, p(1): false, q(1): false, r(1): false