# Stock with long equation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Please i need help with this long equation:

$\neg\forall x\neg(\neg p(x) \lor q(x)) \rightarrow \neg\exists x(\neg p(x) \land \neg q(x)) \models \forall x(p(x) \lor q(x))$.

I am solving with resolution method. Below is what i have done, and was stock.

$\neg\forall x(p(x) \lor q(x))$

$\neg\forall x\neg(\neg p(x) \lor q(x))$

$\forall x(\neg p(x) \land \neg q(x))$

$\neg p(a) \land \neg q(a)$

$\neg\forall x(p(x) \lor q(x))\lor \neg\exists x(\neg p(x) \land \neg q(x))$

$\exists x\neg(\neg p(x) \lor q(x)) \lor \neg\exists x(\neg p(x) \land \neg q(x))$

$\exists x(p(x) \land \neg q(x)) \lor \neg\exists x(\neg p(x) \land \neg q(x))$

$\exists x\exists y((p(x)\land \neg q(x)) \lor p(y) \land q(y)$

Comment: You have posted this very same question 24 hours ago  (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3735842), then, some hours ago, a question connected to this one without mentionning it and without mentionning that you have had contructive comments... (in particular from me). Posting again and again the same question is a bad way to use this site.

Comment: This is not the same question. This is a different equation, though similar.

Comment: All right, not exactly the same one, I recognize, but so similar ...  taking the negation of the RHS of $\vDash$ is OK but should be $¬p(a) ∧ ¬q(b)$ ; morover, I don't see that you really "add" it to the LHS formiulas with connector $ ∨$ and look for a $\square$ (materializing a contradiction)

Comment: Why i haven't understood it is because i have never studied logic before. So every thing is very weired and difficult. I am trying hard to to make this my last question on this site, so if you can solve it the way you write it, please help me with it. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'm going to change a bit the left part ($p\rightarrow q\equiv \neg p \vee q$ and De Morgan's rule). So we have to show $$\forall x (p(x)\wedge q(x))\vee\forall x(p(x)\vee q(x))\models \forall x (p(x)\vee q(x)).\quad \quad \quad(1)$$ Using the resolution method, we have to negate the right part and arrive to a contradiction. So, negating the right part we have $$\exists x \neg( p(x)\vee q(x)).$$ With this we know there is an element $a$ such that $$\neg (p(a)\vee  q(a)).\quad\quad\quad (2)$$ Now using the left part of $(1)$ we know that for $x=a$ this stands (for both quantifiers), so we have $$(p(a)\wedge \neg q(a))\vee p(a)\vee q(a),$$ which you can show that is equivalent to $$p(a)\vee q(a).$$ Combining the last equation with $(2)$ we get that $$p(a)\vee q(a)\wedge \neg(p(a)\vee q(a)),$$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks alot for your contribution